# Can I use the a dictionary key in an API call? (Python)

Tags: python, json, encoding, request

I would think there is not problem with that, but I am really having troubles with this piece of code and cannot seem to come up with a solution.

I have a dictionary whose keys are proper name, e.g. John Green, and I am using the API of the Sunlight Foundation to retrieve information about congress members ([check here](http://services.sunlightlabs.com/docs/Sunlight_Congress_API/)). Now I need to request using name and lastname so my code looks something like this:

```
 for key in my_dict:
   query_params2 = { 'apikey': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                 'firstname' : key.split()[0],
                 'lastname' : key.split()[-1]
                  }
   endpoint2 = "http://services.sunlightlabs.com/api/legislators.get.json"
   resp2 = requests.get(endpoint2, params = query_params2)
   data2 = resp2.json().decode('utf-8')
   print data2['response']['legislator']['bioguide_id']
```

Which gives some error I can not really interpret:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "my_program.py", line 102, in <module>
data = resp.json()
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 741, in json
return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I would guess it has something to do with the encoding, but I am not sure what and how to solve it.

Needless to say, if I put by hand a name and lastname, the request works perfectly.

Anybody can help with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps it works for some keys but not others. Try ignoring the error inside the loop (i.e. just `pass`) and see what you get at the end.

Comment: The error message is saying (1) that your traceback doesn't match your code [code has `.decode()`, tb doesn't], and (2) that you are not getting a JSON object back..

Comment: what is the response (`resp2`) you get?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the encoding.  The answer simply isn't JSON.  When I try your code with 'John' and 'Green' I get a `400 Bad Request` and the content of the response is 'No Such Object Exists'.

Trying *John Green* in the web interface also comes up with an empty answer.  Also the URL in the API documentation differs from the URL in your example.

The following works for me (again no John Green):

```
import requests

LEGISLATORS_URL = 'https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators'
API_KEY = 'xxxx'


def main():
    names = [('John', 'Green'), ('John', 'Kerry')]
    for first_name, last_name in names:
        print 'Checking', first_name, last_name
        response = requests.get(
            LEGISLATORS_URL,
            params={
                'apikey': API_KEY,
                'first_name': first_name,
                'last_name': last_name,
                'all_legislators': 'true'
            }
        ).json()
        print response['count']
        if response['count'] > 0:
            print response['results'][0]['bioguide_id']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Checking John Green
0
Checking John Kerry
1
K000148
```